# Rails: Is there a gem for handling dynamic fields presentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata

I'm starting on a project in a few weeks which is a webapp that handles websites in several languages for subsidiaries of the same company. Although the frontend may look differently they all subscribe to the same model design underneath it.

But one of the main requirements is that each subsidiary can choose which fields of a model will be displayed on their website.

For example: There's a `Program` model

```
class Program < AR
  attr_accessible :starting_at, :ending_at, :name, :price, :country
end
```

So if I have two subsidiaries of this company, i.e. US and Sweden, they both use the same model for presenting programs. But the US branch wants to show a table with all the programs and for each program only show `starting_at`, `ending_at`, `name` and `price`. The Sweden branch wants to do the same but doesn't want to show `ending_at` but `country`.

Furthermore they want to be able to select which fields are going to be displayed through a web interface, because it can change over time.

So my thought was - since there's a lot of meta modeling going on - to come up with a `MetaProgram` model, or so, which holds the information which field for which subsidiary should be displayed, etc. But this would result in dynamic SQL statements with `ActiveRecord`, since I always have to select which fields must be selected, to then select the actual data to present it through the frontend...

Is there a better solution for this, or a gem that treads along this kind of stuff?

PS: Sorry for the ambiguous title

Comment: I think it would require writing super advanced cms to have this as you described it above.

Comment: But maybe you can get the same result easier simply not showing fields that are nil/empty?

Comment: Can't do the latter, cause the fields won't be empty. It's simply not wished, that those are shown on a summary level, but on a detailed info label. And yes, it is sort of a super cms :-)

Comment: Other idea is that maybe translations with Globalized may be employed so certain fields would not be shown depending on language

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for.

I use [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) for this. It's like a key/value storage for your model.

You have a table like this:

```
create_table do |t|
  t.text :metadata # just a text column, will store serialized hash
end
```

And a model like this:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base     
  store :metadata, :accessors => [:starting_at, :ending_at]

  # validate like normal fields
  validates :starting_at, :presence => true
end
```

You just need to find a way to add the store accessors hash dynamically based on the conditions you mentioned in your question.

It might be a disadvantage that stored metadata can not be indexed and you are not able to use them in queries.

I found a nice little tutorial and explanation on this topic [here](http://blog.chrisblunt.com/rails-3-storing-model-metadata-attributes-with-activerecordstore/).

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out! I'm not sure yet if I would need such columns in queries. But I am wondering if this functionality could be combined with Postgres' HStore possibility...

Comment: I think this gem is exactly what you are looking for: https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore